# Laravel - Submitting blog post without showing in database?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

As I am still learning and loving it so far, I have reached another stumbling block. On my blog page, I have a simple form setup with name and body. When I submit the completed form it resets the form looking like it was passed through to the database. But, it was not. When I refresh MySQL nothing happens. However, if I pass test data on MySQL it does pass through without an issue. (Stack: Laravel, PHP, MySQL, HTML/CSS, TailWindCSS)

My question is when I submit the blog post how do I ensure it is passed through to MySQL database?

Blog Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Blog;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class BlogController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $blogs = \App\Blog::all();

        return view ('blog.index', compact('blogs'));

    }

    public function store()
    {
        $data = request()->validate([
            'title' => 'required|min:5',
            'blog' => 'required'
        ]);

        \App\Blog::create($data);

       return redirect()->back();

    }

    public function create()
    {
        $blogs = \App\Blog::all();

        return view ('blog.create', compact('blogs'));
    }

    public function show()
    {
        return view('blog.index');
    }
}
```

Migration Table

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreatesBlogsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('blogs', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->string('body');
            $table->timestamps();

        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('blogs');
    }
}
```

Routes

```
use App\Mail\WelcomeMail;

Route::get('/email', function() {
    return new WelcomeMail();
});

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
Route::get('/about', 'HomeController@about');
Route::get('/contact', 'HomeController@contact');

Route::get('/blog', 'BlogController@index');
Route::get('/blog/create', 'BlogController@create');
Route::get('/blog/{blog}', 'BlogController@show');
Route::post('/blog', 'BlogController@store');
```

App\Blog

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Blog extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];
}
```

Comment: Show the `App\Blog` class code

Comment: @Finesse App\Blog added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your controller code, we can see your form is passing (at least) 2 fields, `title`, and `blog`:

```
$data = request()->validate([
    'title' => 'required|min:5',
    'blog' => 'required'
]);
```

Checking your migration though, there is no `blog` field in your table:

```
$table->bigIncrements('id');
$table->string('title');
$table->string('body');
$table->timestamps();
```

It looks like the `blog` field on the form and in your controller code should really be `body` - or maybe vice-versa, the migration should create a `blog` field.

In any case, your controller tries to `create()` a record using `title`, and `blog`, but not `body`.

The migration specifies that neither `title` nor `body` can be null ([you would use `->nullable()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations#column-modifiers) to allow that), neither does it specify a default value for those fields ([you would use `->default('foo')`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations#column-modifiers) for that).  So if you try to create a record that is missing a value for the `body` field, which is not allowed to be null, and which has no default value, MySQL will fail.

As mentioned in another answer, make sure you have your [mass assignment set up](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#mass-assignment) correctly, so `title` and `body` (or `blog`!) can be filled.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify either a `fillable` or `guarded` attribute on the model, as all Eloquent models protect against mass-assignment by default. Add the following attribute to the `App\Blog` class:

```php
protected $fillable = ['title', 'blog'];
```

[Source and examples](https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#mass-assignment)

Answering the question: Laravel throws an exception when it fails to save a model to the database. In this case the `POST /blog` endpoint adds a record to the log file (`storage/logs/laravel.log`) and returns a response with 503 status (server error). Check your frontend code to see whether it handles error responses or just ignores them.

Comment: @Fitnesse I do have protected $guarded = []; in App\Blog class. Also, I am not getting any errors I did check the log as you indicated, passed through another blog post, no errors evident. Refreshing MySQL no info was passed through.

Comment: I've no idea what's going on in your code. Try to use a PHP debugger or put debug echos amongst the code to see what happens.

Comment: @Fitnesse I have updated the routes code and the blogController. Anything sticking out now? I appreciate your help with this.